# What's the best way to fix this missing solder pad?

Tags: pcb, soldering, repair

During a repair of a mixer, I had to desolder the XLR output jacks in order to remove the front panel. When I started to resolder them I noticed that an pad (or eyelet? not sure of the difference) is missing. Maybe I damaged it during desoldering and didn't notice? In any case, I'd like to find the most durable way to repair it.

I've looked for solutions, but they all seem to be meant for single-sided PCBs. Ideally I'd like to replace it entirely, but any instructions I found for that look like they require specialized tools.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that pad (and another one as well) is not connected to any trace on this side. If you can solder it on the other side it should be sufficient.

If you cannot access it on the other side then one simple solution would be to find where that trace goes and solder piece of wire between jack pin(s) and any of the other pads on same net.

This will probably not hold the jack in place though, so some epoxy can be used on the other side to fix it to PCB.

Comment: View full size image. It looks like pins L + M have a common pad and R a pad of its own. Maybe all 3 are joined even.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I'd rather not epoxy it, because it might need to be removed again in the future to disassemble the unit, which is annoying. But the jack has two screws that fix it to the front panel, so they should be sufficient to hold it in place.